# CDK not adding tags to resources

Tags: typescript, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I'm trying to add a certain Tag to a log group, and it is not being added. I checked cdk.out. It is not there, and of course, it is not added to the resource itself.

```
      const lg = new LogGroup(this, `${id}-lg`, {
        logGroupName: `/aws/appsync/apis/${this.graphQLApi.attrApiId}`,
        removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      });
      Tags.of(lg).add('test', 'works');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We contacted AWS, it turns out that Tags are not supported by Cloudformation for Log groups, and consequently it is not supported by CDK.

Answer (score 0):

Tags are not always supported in CDK or CloudFormation (CDK is effectively a generator of CloudFormation templates) even when the AWS resources themselves support it. CDK is still a relatively new project with a rapid release train, hence in some cases it is difficult to tell if it is working as designed or a minor bug.

CloudFormation's [AWS::Logs::LogGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html) resource presently does not have tagging support. As of May 2021, a PR to add tags via CloudFormation has [recently been merged](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-resource-providers-logs/pull/53) but is awaiting public release. Hence CDK/CloudFormation does not support tagging of this resource at this time - it is likely a CDK update will need to be released after this functionality is available publicly in CloudFormation.

A way to verify if tag is supported is to apply tags to all the resources using the CDK aspect. See [Tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tagging.html). By replacing `myConstruct` with the entire CDK app construct, all the resources in the CDK app will inherit the tag. This is an easy way to apply project-wide tag e.g. project code, environment tags.

```
Tags.of(myConstruct).add('key', 'value');
```

This can be done via core.Tag.add as well.

```
# In Python
from aws_cdk import (
    core
)
core.Tag.add(
    scope=app,
    key=key,
    value=value
)
```

If an AWS resource created via CDK does not have the tag, then we can say CDK does not support tagging for the resource.

Make sure to search the CDK GitHub issues. Otherwise you may spend ours troubleshooting your issues and then find out it is a CDK bug.